# Difference between assigning dimensions and percentage attribute in layout props

Tags: react-native

When i try to run the app, my app behaves differently to the below two methods

```
height: 15%(Dimensions.get('window').height);
// above is not program just my sum up
```

and

```
height:'15%'
```

when I try to set the height to my text input with two methods my apps behave differently, is there any reasons behind it ?

I am in react-native 0.61.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving from Dimension **always** takes the screen window's height/width. However, giving with the string `%` percentage would not take the whole screen window's height, width. If there is a wrapper around the View (or element object) it will calculate the wrapper's height/width. For example:

```
<View style={{ height: 100, width: 300 }}>
   <View style={{ height: "10%", width: "10%" }} />
</View>
```

Inside of the View has `10 height & 30 width` it will calculate from parent view. However, if you will take it from Dimension, it will calculate from the whole screen window's height/width.